# Strange Eco Template Behavior

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, eco

I am using Backbone and Eco templates in my Rails application. My template has the following code:

```
  <% @collection.each (model)-> %>
    <% console.log model.get('name') %>
    <p><%= model.get('name') %></p>
    <p><%= model.get('description') %></p>
  <% end %>
```

For some reason, the HTML is blank. The name and description are not displayed. However, the `console.log` method outputs the correct data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I figured out the missing character. Apparently, Eco templates require a colon after the arrow:

```
<% @collection.each (model)->: %>
```

Not sure why this is the case. It's never mentioned in the readme.

Comment: ["CoffeeScript is whitespace-sensitive, but your templates aren't. Therefore, Eco code tags that begin an indented CoffeeScript block must be suffixed with a colon. To indicate the end of an indented block, use the special tag `<% end %>`."](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco#a-note-about-whitespace)

Comment: Yes, but none of the block examples in the readme adhere to this syntax: https://github.com/sstephenson/eco#blocks-and-capturing

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder if the behavior is context sensitive, do you still need the colon if the first thing in the template isn't a `<%...%>`?

Comment: I don't know. I filed an issue on GitHub. It's either a mistake in the documentation or a bug in the behavior.